# Who picked 127.0.0.1 to be localhost and why? What meaning does it have?

Tags: networking, localhost

I'm almost positive everyone on here knows the meaning of 127.0.0.1.  But, why is that ALWAYS localhost? 
Who picked that arbitrary IP? Why was that IP picked?
Why not something more simple such as 1.0.0.0? Is there some special meaning to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: There is another forum called Server Fault where this question would receive more knowledgeable attention.

Comment: Thank you Marc.  I would also be curious to know why the -1

Comment: See RFC 1700 and what it refers to.

Comment: Hi James, not from me, I was trying to be helpful, not critical.  As an aside, RFC means "Request for Comments", RFC 1700 can be found at http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1700.txt

Comment: You were very helpful, Marc.  Thank you for the neutralization ;). Also, thank you for the link - I will be sure to check it out.

Comment: There are three subnets defined as private subnets - e.g. they are never allowed to be publicly facing IP addresses. This means that you can use these subnets on internal networking and be certain that they will only ever refer to local addresses. 127.x.x.x is one of them, 192.168.x.x is the second and I forget the third :)

Comment: @Patashu, in addition to 192.168.x.x there are 10.x.x.x and 172.16-31.x.x. (See RFC 1918).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RFC means "Request for Comments"

RFC 1700 can be found at http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1700.txt

This may give you more insight into how the IP's are allocated for localhost and so on.

Actually, a better reference is the following:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc820

Certain IP addresses are reserved and 127.0.0.1 is one of them.

Some of the founding fathers/mothers of the internet decided that this was a good idea and we have been happy enough since that time.